# Google Accompanist Permissions SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using [Google Accompainst](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/#jetpack-compose-permissions) library in my android jetpack compose project to request permissions.
I am trying to request **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** permission, but it is not working.

**permissionState.status** is always **Denied(shouldShowRationale=false)**

### My Code

```
@Composable
fun Screen(){

    val drawOverPermission = Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

    val drawOverPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = drawOverPermission)

// ...basic scaffold... 
   Button(onClick = {
      drawOverPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() // not working
     },
   )

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` is not a runtime permission. That has to be granted manually by the user in Settings.

Comment: how can i redirect user to this screen?

Comment: See [the JavaDocs for the permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) for details.